How to add the result of st_centroid to postgresql json response
WITH center AS (
  SELECT
    ST_X(st_centroid(centroid)) AS longitude,
    ST_Y(st_centroid(centroid)) AS latitude
  FROM (
    SELECT st_centroid(
      st_transform(
        st_collect(
          array(
            SELECT location::geometry FROM meetup
            WHERE st_dwithin(location, st_point(yyy.yyyyyy, xx.xxxxxx), 10000)
          )
        )
      , 4326)
    ) AS centroid
  ) AS subquery
)
select row_to_json(result) from (
  select 
    count(*) as total,
    json_agg(json_build_object('longitude', CAST(center.longitude AS TEXT), 'latitude', CAST(center.latitude AS TEXT))) as center, -- this line
    array_to_json(
      array_agg(row_to_json(t)), true) as data from (
        select 
          m.id, 
          m.name,
          st_y(location::geometry) as lat, 
          st_x(location::geometry) as long, 
          st_distance(location, st_point(yyy.yyyyyy, xx.xxxxxx)::geography) as dist_in_km,
        from public.meetup as m
        CROSS JOIN center c
        where st_dwithin(location,st_point(yyy.yyyyyy, xx.xxxxxx)::geography, 10000.0)
          AND m.start_at > current_timestamp
        order by location <-> st_point(yyy.yyyyyy, xx.xxxxxx)::geography
    ) t
  ) result;

To obtain the center coordinates from lat and long of the meetup table, I added the json_agg line to add the coordinates obtained using st_centroid in the with clause to the json object, but an error occurs.
If you exclude the json_agg line, the code works normally.
The desired result is as follows:
{
 "total": 6,
 "center": {"latitude": yyy.yyyyyy, "longitude": xxx.xxxxxx},
 "data": [{"id": 1, "name": "name1", "latitude": yyy.yyyyyy, "longitude": xxx.xxxxxx, "dist_in_km": 396.4184}, ...]
}

error message is below(error message from supabase sql editor)
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "center"
     json_agg(json_build_object('longitude', CAST(center.longitude AS TEXT), 'latitude', CAST(center.latitude AS TEXT))) as center,



You had a trailing comma after dist_in_km.
You aliased center as c so you can no longer reference center as center, only as c.
The alias works only within the same subquery. You can't use it one level up or down, which is what you tried to do. Outside subquery you named t, contents of c (center) are not available unless t selects them from it.
If you are re-using the center coords you obfuscated as yyy.yyyyyy and xx.xxxxxx anywhere you need them, there is no need to cross join to the center in your t subquery, at all.
If you only need the center as one single flat json object in your target structure, you can use a scalar subquery with a to_json() to transform the whole cte that way.
Make sure you're aware what units your geography and geometry typed values use. The former defaults to using distances in meters but coordinate units in degrees. The latter depends on the SRID of the geometry.

demo at db<>fiddle
WITH center AS (
  SELECT
    ST_X(st_centroid(centroid)) AS longitude,
    ST_Y(st_centroid(centroid)) AS latitude
  FROM (
    SELECT st_centroid(
      st_transform(
        st_collect(
          array(
            SELECT location::geometry FROM meetup
            WHERE st_dwithin(location, st_point(2, 2,4326)::geography, 3e5)
          )
        )
      , 4326)
    ) AS centroid
  ) AS subquery )
select row_to_json(result) from (
  select 
    count(*) as total,
    (select to_json(center) from center) as center, -- this line
    array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(t)), true) as data 
  from (select 
          m.id, 
          m.name,
          st_y(location::geometry) as lat, 
          st_x(location::geometry) as long, 
          st_distance(location, st_point(2, 2, 4326)::geography) as dist_in_km
        from public.meetup as m
        where st_dwithin(location,st_point(2, 2, 4326)::geography, 3e5)
          AND m.start_at > current_timestamp
        order by location <-> st_point(2, 2, 4326)::geography
    ) t
  ) result;




row_to_json




{    "data": [        {            "id": 2,            "lat": 2,            "long": 2,            "name": "name2",            "dist_in_km": 0        },        {            "id": 3,            "lat": 3,            "long": 3,            "name": "name3",            "dist_in_km": 156829.32911607        }    ],    "total": 2,    "center": {        "latitude": 2,        "longitude": 2    }}



